# Why middle block of 3DES is decryption rather than encryption?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

hey can someone answer these 3 questions please

1. Why middle block of 3DES is decryption rather than encryption? 2. Suppose an error occurs in a block of ciphertext during transmission from the sender to
   receiver. What effect will be observed on the recovered plaintext at the receiver? 3. Inclusion of salt in UNIX password scheme is the difficulty of guessing password by 4096. However, the salt value is stored in pain-text as same entry as ciphertext. The salt value is known to attacker and need not be guessed. Then why is it asserted that salt increases security?

Comment: Salting prevents looking up known, [pre-computed hash values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table), and they make it impossible to say if two inputs are the same (i.e. if two users use the same password). They are not intended to make guessing less viable.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's off topic.

Comment: The salt value does not make the password harder to guess. That's not why it's there. I'll bet the [wikipedia article on salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) says why it's there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's decryption with a different key to the first encryption.

Decrypting with the wrong key will further convolute the output.

3DES is a `feistel` cipher structure, encryption and decryption are symmetrical.

The reason triple DES is of the form EDE is for one reason, and one reason only: to make it compatible with single DES - thanks to @James Polk

Comment: updated answer...